# Headphones not Working On windows 7

Tags: windows-7, headphone-jack

I just updated my PC from Windows Xp to Windows 7.My headphones were working perfectly before until I got Windows 7.Here it doesn't work but my internal built-in speakers are working normally..no problem in headphones..driver is also present..i also tried to make AUX JACK as default but still it doesnt makes sound..what to do now ??

Comment: Your headphones have drivers?  What make/model of headphones are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headphone jack not working in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/545726/headphone-jack-not-working-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other headphones to see if the input is still working? Also, if they are USB headphones, you might want to try to run them in the Compatibility Center: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Device%20Stage&subcategory=All