# Headphone not working on Dell laptop with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, audio

My headphone has suddenly stopped working. I am not getting any sound from the headphone. I tried 3 different working headphones.

I have dual boot option with Ubuntu & Windows 7. The headphone works when laptop is booted with Ubuntu

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver both previous and newer versions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you right click the playback tab, are **Show Disabled Devices** and **Show Disconnected Devices** both checked?

Comment: @techturtle Yup. Both are Checked.

Comment: USB headphones, or 3.5mm jack headphones?

Comment: @Darius 3.5mm Jack Headphone.

Comment: You can test the headphone with other machine

Comment: @StephenTan HI, The headphones works fine. It works on the same laptop when it is running Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headphone jack not working in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/545726/headphone-jack-not-working-in-windows-7)